# Adding a Class when a certain class exists in nested element

Tags: jquery, css

So I have HTML like below. You'll notice there are two sets. I'd like to use jQuery to add a class "free" to the wpem-single-event-widget div when the "free" class exists at the most nested level.

Ideally, the first div would be:

```
<div class="wpem-main wpem-single-event-widget free">
```

Is this possible?

```
<div class="wpem-main wpem-single-event-widget">
  <a href="URL">
    <div class="wpem-event-banner">
      <div class="wpem-event-banner-img"><img src="URL" alt="A Thing" scale="0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wpem-event-infomation">
         <div class="wpem-event-details">
           <div class="wpem-event-type">
             <span class="wpem-event-type-text event-type **free** ">Free</span>                
           </div>                 
         </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="wpem-main wpem-single-event-widget">
  <a href="URL2">
    <div class="wpem-event-banner">
      <div class="wpem-event-banner-img"><img src="URL" alt="A Thing 2" scale="0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wpem-event-infomation">
         <div class="wpem-event-details">
           <div class="wpem-event-type">
             <span class="wpem-event-type-text event-type">Not Free</span>              
           </div>                 
         </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:has()` selector modifier to test if there's something contained.

```js
$(".wpem-single-event-widget:has(.free)").addClass("free");
```

```css
div.free {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpem-main wpem-single-event-widget">
  <a href="URL">
    <div class="wpem-event-banner">
      <div class="wpem-event-banner-img"><img src="URL" alt="A Thing" scale="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpem-event-infomation">
      <div class="wpem-event-details">
        <div class="wpem-event-type">
          <span class="wpem-event-type-text event-type free">Free</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="wpem-main wpem-single-event-widget">
  <a href="URL2">
    <div class="wpem-event-banner">
      <div class="wpem-event-banner-img"><img src="URL" alt="A Thing 2" scale="0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpem-event-infomation">
      <div class="wpem-event-details">
        <div class="wpem-event-type">
          <span class="wpem-event-type-text event-type">Not Free</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it search down multiple levels?

Comment: Yes, did you try it?